# Check if input string is part of 2 dim array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, compare, contains

I'm trying to check if a string is part of a 2dim array.

`geefNamenCat` returns `Input.readString()`. Is there any way for me to easily check if `geefNamenCat` is part of `TERADENWOORDEN[ ][ ]`?. I've been browsing this site for quite a while now and I have only found solutions for 1dim arrays (which I couldn't get to work either).

```
    public void catKiezen() {
        do { 
        String gekozenCat = geefNamenCat("\nKies 1 van de volgende categorieën: ");
        }
        while ( !gekozenCat.equals (TERADENWOORDEN[][]) 
    }
```

Edit: I forgot to add, the do/while thing is so that it would keep asking for a new input until the given input is part of the array

Comment: Part - in which direction? When read as text? Right or down? Left, right, up or down? Any of the eight directions? Is it a rectangle? A torus? ... The hungarian (or what it is) doesn't help understanding.

Comment: Or is it a 2D array of strings, and the input must be present in any cell? I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: The array reads lines from a txt file. Basicly you have 2 columns and x amount of rows, where x = amount of lines in the txtfile. Thanks

Comment: Your second comment is correct, sorry if I didn't explain well enough. It needs to check if the input string is part of the array (which is a String array). preferably it should only check the first column, but that's not really an issue.

Comment: `TERA...DEN` is the 2d array?

Comment: Is the size of the 2D array defined/specified?

Comment: Checking one column is _slightly_ easier than checking two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
boolean contains = false;

do {
    String gekozenCat = geefNamenCat("\nKies 1 van de volgende categorieën: ");

    for (String[] sub : Arrays.asList(TERADENWOORDEN))
        if (Arrays.asList(sub).contains(gekozenCat)) {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }

    if (! contains) {
        // print something
    }

} while (! contains);
```

Comment: No need to cast to a List; also, you might be facing unchecked casts (Object => String[][]) (error) this way.

Comment: @JanDvorak There is no cast here.

Comment: @JanDvorak The question is: would the quick containment test of the `HashSet` outweigh the time it takes to construct it. I figured it would but I could definitely be wrong. Also, what unchecked cast are you talking about?

Comment: You have to import `java.util.HashSet` and `java.util.Arrays`. Also, you should put `boolean contains = false` outside the loop and the rest of the code inside. Then the loop condition would be `! contains`.

Comment: @A.R.S. since you're building a new hashSet each time... I assume that it does take much longer.

Comment: ah sorry, forgot HashSet, my bad

Comment: Still getting errors on contains(gekozenCat) (cannot find symbol)

Comment: Note that this fails the requirement that `preferably it should only check the first column`.

Comment: This actually works. nice one. Just one more minor thing. Say I wanted to display a message after typing something in the input that does not belong to the array, where do I put this? just add else to the if? Going to upvote this too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's right Jan, if you could come up with something that does, that would be great. But it's not really needed

Comment: @Jente mine does, and it's shorter as well.

Comment: @Jente You could just put an `if (! contains) {...}` at the end of the loop body. See my edit.

Comment: Sry I had to go out for a bit. Let me try yours now then :). This one certainly works though if someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments:

> Basicly you have 2 columns and x amount of rows
>
> preferably it should only check the first column

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
for(String[] row: ALLOWED_WORDS){
  if(input.equals(row[0])){
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Also, if you expect multiple queries over the same table, you might consider compiling the table into a hashSet:

```
//once
HashSet<String> allowedWordList = new HashSet<String>();
for(String[] row: ALLOWED_WORDS){
  allowedWordList.add(row[0])
}

//on each check
if(allowedWordList.contains(input)){
  ...
}
```

Also, based on

> The array reads lines from a txt file

Then it's not a constant and should not be all-caps: `ALLOWED_WORDS` => `allowedWords`

Comment: It actually reads it from a text file on startup into a final so I guess I should be going with the all caps one. Let me try this

Comment: All-caps normally signify compile-time constants only. However, I do understand your thinking.

Comment: I can't get this to work properly, probably something on my end though. input should be geefNamenCat and allowedWordList should be TERADENWOORDEN for me, correct?

Comment: @Jente I think so. Note that my code doesn't include the outer loop (reading in repeatedly).